# Moving Picture Box depending on monitor size? C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube

I am using a picture box in my C# application, I want it to cover a certain portion of the web browser (the username part on youtube).

I have a 21.5" monitor and this is what it looks like to me:

[image]

But then this is what it looks like to one of my users with a 24" monitor:

[image]

As you can see the position of the picture box has moved up due to that persons screen size (I believe)

Is there a way to make sure that it will always be over that section of the web browser or moving it to that section of the web browser?

Thanks.

Comment: ahm ... can you show us what you did so far? Is this a webbrowser-control in a winforms application or what?

Comment: This is a webBrowser control in a windows form, full screen image is here: http://i.imgur.com/QD2qm.png 

What I want todo is block out the username & videos part, I do this by setting that picture box visible when a youtube video comes up, but as above the position of the pictureBox changes dependent on monitor size, looking for a way to make sure it covers the username.

Comment: The code is simply `pictureBox1.Visible = true;` to set it visible, false to hide it, not sure what else  I should provide.

Comment: for example the way you calculate the position of the picturebox

Comment: I don't have any code for that, I have just positioned it on the form designer.

Comment: Type Ctrl = to arbitrarily mess up your plan, regardless of the monitor.  Look at HtmlElement.ClientRectangle for a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am convinced your approach is wrong and would break anytime either for screen resolution or size changes, or for using the mouse-wheel to zoom in/out the page or whatever. it is just unreliable and patching this by overlapping another UI control like a picture box or a panel on top of what you want to hide is simply insecure and unreliable.

I think the tow real options you have are these:

1. You try to interpret the page content and remove from the page's DOM the information you do not want to show to the user (eventually HTML Agility Pack could help for this DOM parsing and manipulation but I am not sure if you can read what the WebBrowser control is showing and inject changes into it);
2. use the [YouTube APIs and Tools - .NET APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) to load the videos and details you want to load and show but rendering this information with your specific UI elements in your windows forms application, without using a browser to show the normal YouTube site.

Probably the second option takes more work but is more secure, I am not sure 100%, as I said, if the first option is viable at all. You could search for HTML Agility Pack and web browser control to see if anybody has done this before already :)

Comment: Thanks very much, looking into the HTML Agility Pack, found some helpful stuff around